# Inserting a new value into an already created file - perl

Tags: perl, file

I have a file created which has data in columns 0, 1 and 2. I now have a new variable called $percentage that has 11 values associated to it that I wish to add to column 3 of the file.

How do I do this without appending to the bottom of the file?

Currently my data looks like, but would like it formatted next to the existing data:

```
title name number 
title name number 
title name number 
title name number 
                  $percentage value 1
                  $percentage value 2
                  $percentage value 3
                  $percentage value 4
```

etc

Comment: Is the edited example data in your question really how your data currently appears?

Comment: have a look at the [`paste`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix)) command line tool. It is dead simple to implement in Perl—you just read from multiple file handles, `chomp` all lines, and print them `join`ed together.

Comment: You could use printf to do this. printf $fh ("%s %s %s %s\n", $title, $name, $number, $val);

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want to do...

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Copy;

my $target_file = "testfile";
my $tmp_file = "$target_file.new";
my $str = "some string with stuff";

open my $fh, "<", "testfile";
open my $w_fh, ">>", "testfile.new";

# loop over your current file, one line at a time
while( my $line = <$fh> ){
    # remove the '\n' so we can add to the existing line
    chomp $line;
    # add what you'd like, plus the '\n'
    my $full_line = "$line $str\n";
    # and print this to a tmp file
    print $w_fh $full_line;
}
close $fh;
close $w_fh;

unlink $target_file or die "unable to delete $target_file: $!";
# use the File::Copy sub 'move'
# to rename the tmp file to the original name
move($tmp_file, $target_file);
```

Running the code:

```
$ cat testfile
this is three
this is three
this is three
$ test.pl
$ cat testfile
this is three some string with stuff
this is three some string with stuff
this is three some string with stuff
```

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings`

Comment: @Kenosis - No kidding, you forgot to state the obvious `shebang` line too ;). Of course this code has `warnings` and `strict` on.

Comment: The `shebang` is needed only if the script's being executed from a shell, e.g., `> ./script.pl`--not if executed using `perl script.pl`.  Only mentioned explicitly showing the use of `strict` and `warnings` at the top of the script for the sake of those new to Perl.

Comment: @Kenosis Yes, of course you only need the `shebang` when it's called without the `interpretor` directly. Which a *very* large amount of time it is. If you were saying it for the OP, then direct the message to him/her. To make sure they get it.

Comment: If you're attempting to assist an OP who's new here--and it is evident you are knowledgeable--why not explicitly model the best practice of using strictures for the benefit of the OP?  You said, "Of course this code has warnings and strict on."  How can the OP possibly know this?

Answer (score 3):

use [Tie::File](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile);

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;
use Tie::File;

tie my @f, 'Tie::File', 'foo' or die $!;

my $n;
for (@f) {
  $_ .= ' $percentage value ' . $n++;
}

untie @f;
```

Example:

```
$ cat foo
title name number
title name number
title name number
title name number
$ perl tie-ex 
$ cat foo
title name number $percentage value 0
title name number $percentage value 1
title name number $percentage value 2
title name number $percentage value 3
```

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings`

Comment: @Kenosis, [no](https://metacpan.org/module/MLEHMANN/common-sense-3.4/sense.pm.PL).

Comment: Well done!  Was not familiar with common::sense.  My apologies.